# What is exactly lvalue context in Rust?

Tags: rust, type-inference

According to [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#lvalues-rvalues-and-temporaries), we have lvalue and rvalue contexts. How do I know if an expression is in an lvalue context? Is it determined just by the side of the expression in an assignment?

To be more concrete, I need to understand when `DerefMut` is used for dereferencing and when `Deref` is used instead? Same with `Index` and `IndexMut`.

Comment: The next two paragraphs of the documentation appear to answer your questions. In particular, this: *The left operand of an assignment or compound-assignment expression is an lvalue context, as is the single operand of a unary borrow. The discriminant or subject of a match expression may be an lvalue context, if ref bindings are made, but is otherwise an rvalue context. All other expression contexts are rvalue contexts.*

Answer (score 9):

You are asking two different questions here.

> To be more concrete, I need to understand, when `DerefMut` is used for dereferencing and when `Deref` is used instead? Same with `Index` and `IndexMut`.

This only depends on whether or not the resulting value is used mutably or not. The expressions using the operators belonging to those traits (`[]` and `*`) are always *lvalue expressions*.

---

Now your more complicated question:

> How do I know, if an expression is in an lvalue context? Is it determined just by the side of the expression in an assignment?

### Expression categories

To recap: what is an rvalue/lvalue *expression*?

- an **rvalue expression** represents **a value**
- an **lvalue expression** represents **a value in a memory location** (or in different words: represents a value which lives somewhere/has a home)

Which expressions are lvalue and which are rvalue expressions? There are only a few **l**value expressions:

- “names” (or rather: paths) which refer to variables (local, function arguments or statics)
- indexing expressions (e.g. `foo[3]`)
- deref expressions (e.g. `*foo`)
- field access expressions (e.g. `foo.bar`)

---

### Context categories

What about rvalue/lvalue *contexts*? These contexts are “slots” inside of expressions. For example, the expression “modulo” (`%`) has two of those slots, the first and the second operand: `⟨first⟩ % ⟨second⟩`. Now these contexts come in two different flavours as well:

- an **rvalue context** is a “slot” where **a value is expected**
- an **lvalue context** is a “slot” where **a memory location is expected**

So which slots are rvalue and which are lvalue contexts? Luckily, the number **l**value contexts is very limited, so here is a full list:

- the left hand side of a (compound-)assignment (e.g. `⟨lvalue context⟩ = ...;` or `⟨lvalue context⟩ += ...;`)
- the operand of an unary borrow (`&⟨lvalue context⟩` and `&mut ⟨lvalue context⟩`)
- whenever something is bound to a pattern in which a `ref` appears (e.g. `let ref x = &⟨lvalue context⟩;`)

---

### Using expression X in context Y

Let's see which *expressions* we can use in which *context*:

- **[R in R]** ***r***value expression in ***r***value context: no problem, the expression is used as value (e.g. the literal `3` on the right hand side of an assignment)
- **[L in L]** ***l***value expression in ***l***value context: no problem, the expression is used as memory location (e.g. a variable name on the left hand side of an assignment)
- **[L in R]** ***l***value expression in ***r***value context: since the context requires a value and the expression represents a “value in a memory location” we can just use the value of the expression. So: it's all fine (e.g. a variable name on the right hand side of an assignment). So we can see: *lvalue expressions* are worth more than *rvalue expressions*.
- **[R in L]** ***r***value expression in ***l***value context: here is where it becomes problematic. The context requires a memory address, but the expression only represents a value. Sometimes, Rust will do an “rvalue promotion” to make situations like this work. This means that Rust will automatically put the value of the expression into a new memory location (a temporary variable) and use that location in the context. For example, `&mut 3` works because of said promotion. This promotion currently doesn't work for assignments, which [seems to be a bug in either the documentation or the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520642/why-isnt-this-rvalue-promoted-to-an-lvalue-as-specified-in-the-reference).

Answer (score 2):

`DerefMut`/`Deref`/`Index`/`IndexMut` are determined by **mutability**, which is a different question from **lvalue/rvalue context**. Mutability makes no sense for rvalue context.

In fact, all four traits require the operand `self` to be in an lvalue context, since they all take `&Self` or `&mut Self` as argument.

`DerefMut`/`IndexMut` are used whenever mutability is needed, e.g.

```
*here = ...;
here[i] = ...;

&mut here
&mut here[i]

here.call_some_mut_method(...)
here[i].call_some_mut_method(...)
```

---

An lvalue context is where you want to know the *address* (memory location / reference / ...) of the expression, instead of its value. The place where you need an lvalue.

> The left operand of an assignment or compound-assignment expression is an lvalue context, …

```
here = ...;

here += ...;
```

> … as is the single operand of a unary borrow.

```
&here

&mut here

let ref ... = here;
// Note: equivalent to `let ... = &here;`

let ref mut ... = here;
// Note: equivalent to `let ... = &mut here;`
```

*Note: This shows an immutable lvalue context*

> The discriminant or subject of a match expression may be an lvalue context, if ref bindings are made, but is otherwise an rvalue context.

```
match here {
    Ok(ref ...) => ...,
    Err(ref mut ...) => ...,
}
```