# What is the difference between assigning an expression to a variable VS just inlining the variable into another expression?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the following code in Rust:

```
fn send_message(_: &[u8]) {}

let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
let string_message = args[1..].join(" ") + "\nEND\n";
let socket_message = string_message.as_bytes();

send_message(&socket_message);
```

This works. However, I wanted to avoid having the `string_message` variable there, so I just inlined that expression in the declaration of socket_message:

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let socket_message = (args[1..].join(" ") + "\nEND\n").as_bytes();

send_message(&socket_message);
```

Rust doesn't think these two snippets are the same, though!

It gives this error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:7:70
   |
7  |     let socket_message = (args[1..].join(" ") + "\nEND\n").as_bytes();
   |                          ---------------------------------           ^ temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
   |                          |
   |                          temporary value created here
...
10 | }
   | - temporary value needs to live until here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

I believe I am missing something related to the borrow checker, but cannot even understand what it might be, because I expected a temporary value that does not even get assigned directly wouldn't have anything to do with borrowing?!

Comment: My guess: Rust needs all heap allocations to live until the end of every function scope, so that it knows what to free when the function invocation goes out of scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the compiler tells you:

```
= note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

... a `let` binding can increase the lifetime of values. Your expression `args[1..].join(" ") + "\nEND\n"` creates a value of type `String`. Values which are created within a statement don't outlive that statement unless they are named (with a let binding) or are being [rvalue promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311825/what-is-exactly-lvalue-context-in-rust/42313956#42313956). The latter case doesn't apply here and since you're not naming your value, it won't outlive the parent statement. Often, this is not really problematic, but if you want to *reference* said value later, you would reference something dead. Hence the complains by the borrow checker.

**In your case, there are two possibilities**:

1. Inline expression enough such that you don't reference values outside of your statement:

   ```
   let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
   send_message(&(args[1..].join(" ") + "\nEND\n").as_bytes());
   ```

   As you can see: we still have the temporary string inside our statement, but it's fine since we only reference it inside of that statement.
2. Use a `let` binding to increase the value's lifetime, as you've done in your first example. You could still shorten your code by one line like so:

   ```
   let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
   let string_message = args[1..].join(" ") + "\nEND\n";

   send_message(string_message.as_bytes());
   ```

Comment: so, `as_bytes()` returns a reference to the result of that expression, but the expression's value itself does not live after that line, so that what `as_bytes()` returns is referencing something dead?

Comment: @Renato (assuming you are talking about the example the produces the compiler error) yes!

Comment: If you want to really minimize the amount of code at the calling location, you can [get it down to 2 lines](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=51ca86397489276026406f2f56bdb6ba&version=stable) (and reduce the number of allocations too)