# What is the meaning of the error "left-hand of expression not valid"?

Tags: rust, ownership

I wrote this code to see what happens when I pass two strings to a function and return them back again:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s3 = String::from("hello");
    let mut s4 = String::from("wolrd");

    (s3, s4) = take_n_giveback(s3, s4);

    println!("{0} and {1}", s3, s4);
}

fn take_n_giveback(x: String, y: String) -> (String, String) {
    (x, y)
}
```

I am getting an error which is not helpful:

```
error[E0070]: invalid left-hand side expression
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     (s3, s4) = take_n_giveback(s3, s4);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ left-hand of expression not valid
```

This operation works fine when passing single string and returning back.

```
fn main() {
    let mut s3 = String::from("hello");
    s3 = take_n_giveback(s3);
    println!("{0} ", s3);
}

fn take_n_giveback(x: String) -> (String) {
    x
}
```

What's wrong here? What is the meaning of the error and in what situations can be encountered in code?

Comment: when you bind a value, you must use let, for example, `let (s3, s4) = ...`

Comment: As i mentioned it works for single variable without using let keyword. then how that happens.

Comment: I think you need to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/47649554/9204 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311825/what-is-exactly-lvalue-context-in-rust.

Comment: the example seems little complicated to me since I am beginner, can you please explain what is fundamental difference between first(not working) and second example(working) in updated question.

Comment: Ok, added an answer.

Comment: Please take the time to go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html), specifically the [section on variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html). Many introductory topics are covered by the book, such as introductory syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
let ... = ... // or let mut
```

is a **binding**: it creates new variables.

```
... = ...
```

(without `let`) is an **assignment**: it changes values of already bound variables (or their parts). See [What's the semantic of assignment in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648958/whats-the-semantic-of-assignment-in-rust/47649554#47649554) for more explanation of this difference.

The left hand of a binding must be a **pattern**; the left hand of an assignment must be an **place expression** (formerly called lvalue). As explained in https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions

> > A place expression is an expression that represents a memory location. These expressions are paths which refer to local variables, static variables, dereferences (`*expr`), array indexing expressions (`expr[expr]`), field references (`expr.f`) and parenthesized place expressions. All other expressions are value expressions.

`(s3, s4)` is a pattern, but it isn't a place expression, because it isn't one of the above; it doesn't represent a fixed memory location.

> This operation works fine when passing single string and returning back.

A variable name, like `s3`, can be used both a pattern and as a place expression. But with different meanings! When it's used in an assignment

```
let mut s3 = String::from("hello");
s3 = take_n_giveback(s3);
```

it represents the location of the variable declared by `let mut s3`, so there is only a single variable; but in

```
let mut s3 = String::from("hello");
let s3 = take_n_giveback(s3);
```

it creates a new variable called `s3`, so there are two different variables which happen to have the same name. This is why it works even if the first one is not `mut`.

Comment: although I have understood how it works, can you explain how it gets a fixed location when we write let (s3, s4) = take_n_giveback(s3, s4)? is it like when we create binding using "let" rust allocates continuous memory location s3 and s4 and then it becomes lvalue?

Comment: `let` uses a pattern, not an lvalue, so `(s3, s4)` here doesn't need a fixed location at all. It does allocate memory locations (on stack) for `s3` and `s4`, but I don't know if they are guaranteed to follow each other.

Comment: Maybe it'll also help to think of something which is a lvalue, but not a pattern: indexing or field acccess. So you can write `s[0] = x;` (for suitable types), but not `let s[0] = x;`.

Comment: I've checked the reference and lvalues are now called place expressions. So the answer has been slightly updated.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `let` keyword; it should be a variable or a let statement:

```
let (s3, s4) = take_n_giveback(s3, s4);
```

Comment: Found this explanation.  https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6d4j9b/invalid_lefthand_side_expression_why/

Answer (score -1):

```
fn main() {
    let s3 = String::from("hello");
    let s4 = String::from("wolrd");

    let (s3, s4) = take_n_giveback(s3, s4);

    println!("{0} and {1}", s3, s4);
}

fn take_n_giveback(x: String, y: String) -> (String, String) {
    (x, y)
}
```